# How to fetch the ID of the table to be stored

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
restaurant_orders with fields order_id, restaurant_id, tot_amt   where order_id is (Autoinc, primary)
order_menus with fields order_id, menu_id, quantity
```

When the user clicks submit button, the record will be stored at `restaurant_orders` with the field `order_id` being automatically generated. Also a record will be stored at `order_menus` table. Both will happen at same time.

What I want is the `order_id` stored in both tables should be the same. How is it possible?

Comment: use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
to get the first id then pass it as order_id to the second table.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but you can get the last insert id using [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and you can use that in your `order_menus` table.

Comment: restaurant_orders and order_menus have an identical number of rows? order_menus has auto increment key?

Comment: Order_menus have no autoinc or primary

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice article that describes how to do what you want:

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/12/04/mysql-how-to-get-the-key-of-last-inerted-row-in-php/

You're going to have to make 2 INSERTs regardless of what you do because that's just how inserting works.  From that article you can do it pure mySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (name) VALUES ('some value')
INSERT INTO tab2 (value, tab1_id) VALUES ('another value', LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

or with php:

```
$last_inserted_row = mysql_insert_id($dblink)
```